# Why didn't Pharaoh Killed Musa As?

Tags: tafseer, prophets, prophet-musa

> And the eminent among the people of Pharaoh said, "Will you leave
> Moses and his people to cause corruption in the land and abandon you
> and your gods?" [Pharaoh] said, "We will kill their sons and keep
> their women alive; and indeed, we are subjugators over them."

Quran 7:127

In this verse we can clearly see pharaoh had the chance to kill Musa As. Instead he totally ignored his people's advice and told them to kill the Children of Israel.

**My question is nothing was preventing pharaoh to kill Musa As. But he didn't, it seems he has some soft side for Musa As. Any scholar said anything about this.  Any reason for pharaoh being soft towards Musa As?**

Answer (score 2):

Several books of tafsir comment on this including Razi and Qurtubi.

The reason Pharaoh didn't try to kill Musa (AS) directly is because he was terrified of him.

It is reported that Mujahid said:

> Musa (AS) used to be terrified of the Pharaoh, and used to make dua to Allah every time he saw him. So, Allah took out what was in the heart of Musa (AS) and put it into the heart of the Pharaoh.

That was reported regarding the following verse:

> [Allah] said, "We will strengthen your arm through your brother and grant you both supremacy so they will not reach you. [It will be] through Our signs; you and those who follow you will be the predominant." (28:35)

Similar statement was reported from Saeed ibn Jubair regarding the verse quoted in the question:

> The Pharaoh used to be filled with terror from Musa (AS), and the people of the Pharaoh did not know this.

This is one of the ways Allah protects His prophets. He puts fear into the hearts of those that might try to kill them. This is also reported in the life of Muhammad (SAW).

Note that later on the Pharaoh did pretend he wanted to kill Musa (AS) as in Surah Ghafir.

The assumption that he had a soft side for Musa (AS) seems unfeasible. The very reason Musa (AS) fled Egypt was because he was about to be killed, and one of the fears he mentioned to Allah from returning to Egypt was that they might kill him.

And Allah knows best.